# Side of the equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

I tried very much but since tomorrow is my exam, i cannot risk it.

The following is a geometry problem, which i have tried very much but could not grasp a solution.

[image: see problem 19]

I think that i require pythagoras' theorem here, but can not understand how to apply it.
I first thought of extending a line congruent to BP such that it intersects CP at a point. But that did not help me. I also have the hint that all the other angles are 60 in measure, but if P were the incentre, in that case it would not have been difficult to show to P is the subtending angle of measure 150 degrees.
Any help would be helpful!

Comment: Another picture on its side :-(

Comment: How will i draw the given figure?

Comment: To be clear: Are you specifically asking about question $19$ in the image? If so, please make an effort to type the text of the problem into your question; it's pretty short. (Questions in images aren't searchable, and they tend to be harder to read ... especially when they aren't right-side-up ;).

Comment: Rotate it

Comment: It is unneccessary. I constructed the diagram myself. I did not take a hint

Comment: Please always remember that you're asking people to spend some of their valuable time helping you. The easier your questions are to read and understand, the less of that time you waste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let in $\Delta ABC$ vertexes by the rotation similar to the clock.

The first problem.

Let $K\in AM$ such that $BM=KM$.

Thus, since
$$\measuredangle BMK=\measuredangle BMA=\measuredangle BCA=60^{\circ},$$
we obtain that $\Delta BMK$ is equilateral triangle.

Now, take $\Delta BAK$ and rotate around point $B$ by $60^{\circ}.$

We obtain that $A$ goes to $C$ and $K$ goes to $M$,

which says $AK=MC$ and
$$BM+MC=MK+AK=AM$$ and we are done!

The second problem.

Take the rotation around $C$ by $60^{\circ}.$

We see that $B$ goes to $A$ and let $M$ goes to $M'$.

Thus, $BM=AM'$ and $MC=MM'$ and we got $\Delta AMM'$ with needed properties.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88560/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-rozenberg-side-of-the-equilateral-triangle).